# how printing exception by a class function that contains the string to print?

Tags: c++, exception, cout

I have this:

```
catch (Except& e) {
  std::cout << e.print() << std::endl;
}
```

I want this to print: `OK you won!`

so I have the class:

```
class Except{
public:
  std::string print() {
    std::string error("OK you won!\n");
    return error;
  }
};
```

I have this error in the Except class: `"'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type"`

Comment: `but its not working...` what exactly is not working?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Every time you explain your problem with "its not working" a programmer dies.

Comment: Returning a message from a function called stack is confusing.

Comment: How are you throwing the exception?

Comment: `print` doesn't print. I'd prefer something like `printable` here.

Answer (score 3):

You have to include the header for `std::string` : `#include <string>`

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Except{
        public:
                std::string stack() {
                        std::string error("OK you won!\n");
                        return error;
                }
};

int main() {
        try {
                throw Except();
        } catch (Except &e) {
                std::cout << e.stack() << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
./a.out
OK you won!
```

Comment: You forgot to `#include <string>` (like the OP, most likely).

Comment: @AndyPowl if he hadnt included iostream, nobody would actually care about this :D

Comment: Yeap, but it is included via iostream header.

Comment: @vershov implementation dependent

Comment: @vershov: You can't rely on that.

Comment: Yes, but it's OK for the test

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not throwing it right - works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Except{
  public:
    std::string stack() {
      std::string error("OK you won!\n");
      return error;
    }
};

int main() {

  try {
    throw Except();
  }  catch (Except& e) {
    std::cout << e.stack() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
};
```

Output:

`OK you won!`

Comment: Same story :) You forgot to `#include <string>`